# Why the EXTERNAL-IP in LoadBalancer Service is always pending?

Tags: kubernetes

I hava a custom Kubernetes Cluster(minikube) and have depleyed Metallb. When I create a LoadBalancer Service, the status is still pending.

Pods is below,

[image: all pods]

minikube ip is `192.168.99.103`,
metallb config file is below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: my-ip-space
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.99.100/28
```

and the service yaml is below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-web-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 82
    targetPort: 8416
  selector:
    app: java
```

Answer (score 1):

Minikube is a single VM test cluster. You need to use [`minikube service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service) command to expose the service.

Assuming you are aim is to try metallb -

[You need to provide address range as `from-to` syntax as follows for layer2.](https://www.shashankv.in/kubernetes/metallb-layer2-mode/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250     ---> This line
```

Comment: You mean, even though I installed metallb, LoadBanlancer Service still doesn't work in minikube, right? 

Essentially `minikube service` is the nodeport approach.

Comment: No. Just letting you know that there is a different way to expose services in minikube without using metallb if your goal is just to expose the service. Coming to metallb, I have not tried metallb inside minikube but l remember the metallb config should be as I've stated in the answer. Did you try changing `192.168.99.103/28` in your metallb configmap  to `from-to` syntax?

Comment: I have tried, but the service is still keeping pending.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart metallb components after changing the configmap. Have you checked the logs of metallb controller?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design.

> On cloud providers that support load balancers, an external IP address
>   would be provisioned to access the Service. On Minikube, the
>   LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the minikube
>   service command.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service